# How to replace the help command in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, console, command-line-interface, symfony4

Currently, I'm working on the Symfony `Console` component to rebuild a CLI application. The problem is replacing the `help` command (or even the `list` command) manually.

Suppose the application file (i.e. where you run the application) is located at `./bin/console.php`. When I run

```
php ./bin/console.php help
```

, it shows me the full help. So, I created a new `HelpCommand` class to handle a customized the output and added it to the application (i.e. using `Symfony\Component\Console\Application::add()` method):

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class HelpCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('help');
        // ...
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln("Worked!");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

After rerunning the command, the `help` command output changed, and the command printed "Worked!".

The problem is that I cannot use commands' helps, however. For example, consider I've defined the `start` command and I want to know its usage; so I would run:

```
php ./bin/console.php start -h
```

This ends up in a fatal error, which looks like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method App\Command\HelpCommand::setCommand() in $ROOT/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:507
Stack trace:
#0 $ROOT/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(667): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->get('list')
#1 $ROOT/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(226): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('list')
#2 $ROOT/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 $ROOT/bin/console.php(22): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in $ROOT/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 507
```

Is there any other solutions or any fixes for this? Also, I worry about future problems, about something unexpected to happen with these changes to the `help` command.

Thanks in advance. Note that I'm using Composer.

Comment: Not really sure why you would need to do this but I think you will need to copy the entire existing HelpCommand over and modify accordingly.  Normally I would try to extend it but it contains a private variable (containing the name of the command you want help for) so that won't (pardon the pun) help much.

Comment: @Cerad A reason to do this is that I want to create a command file which automatically calls the application file with the passed arguments, and use that command file instead of running `php ./bin/console.php`. For instance, I want to create a file named "app" in the root directory, and then run the application by doing (in Linux) `./app`. However, when user requests the help, the application help, for printing commands list, shows "php ./bin/console.php help list", not "app help list". BTW, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hmmm.  Have your tried moving and renaming bin/console to ./app.  Pretty sure that the help command will use the actual filename.  You will probably still get the php because that is how unix works but this seems like quite an effort for little benefit.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but I'm not sure. Will the solution work in Android the same as Linux? Also, there're some other reasons to do that. I don't want my help to have such options as `--raw` or `--verbose`.

Comment: It should run the same because it's really the php interpreter that is dealing with this sort of thing.  I will have to admit that the very notion of running php on an Android device sounds a bit crazy but I did some searching and it actually seems to be a thing.  Good luck.  Maybe write an article once your app is running.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks! It's not going to be a usual app, but a CLI tool to run in terminal, even on Android. It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/machitgarha/dej). Maybe I want to show others the power of PHP to create powerful tools! :)